# IsNull() extention for checking null value for any object

Tags: c#, .net, null, extension-methods

I am adding new [extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) method for checking [`null`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx) value for any object on following criteria:

1. Should return `true` if value for `class object` is `null`
2. Should return `true` if object is of type `string` and having value [`null` or `Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. Should return `true` if object is of type `DateTime` and having [`Min value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
4. Any other condition for `null` need to check.(Please suggest if required.)

Here is `IsNull()` extention method:

```
 public static bool IsNull(this object obj)
 {
     if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
        return true;

     if (obj.GetType() == typeof(string))
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString());

     if (obj.GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
     {
        DateTime _dateValue = DateTime.MinValue;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(obj.ToString(), out _dateValue) && _dateValue == DateTime.MinValue)
        return true;
     }

     return false;
 }
```

Now my question is:

1. Do I need to add check differently for Value and Reference type
   object?
2. Does this extension method handle all type of `null` check for any
   object?
3. Any suggestion or improvement need to add in extension?

Comment: I don't get it. You're writing an extension and you need us to tell you what it should do? So why are you writing it? And btw. `string.Empty` is an empty string, not `null`, `DateTime.Min != null` either. I don't really get why you need that kind of method.

Comment: If you want extension methods that act differently based on type, write extension methods on *those types*.

Comment: For code review goto http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes you can say that method isnt for checking null but for min requirement for particular object type(string, DateTime).

Comment: Please reserve the use of "null" to mean the [default value of reference-type variables and nullable value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/edakx9da(v=vs.120).aspx). Qualify it when you mean something else: [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx). Use a conjunction when you want to combine it with other meanings: [IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) and [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

A few observations:

1) A value type will never be `null`. When called on a value type.. it will be boxed to an `object`.. and won't be `null` (unless you wrap it in a `Nullable<T>`).

2) Your method no longer checks for `null`.. it also checks for a minimum value and empty strings. An empty string is not `null` - its an empty value. A minimum value is not `null`.. its a value. It has too much responsibility here and should be renamed.

3) Given what I've said above.. you could just simply do this instead of writing your own function:

```
if (variable == default(variable.GetType()))
```

Since that checks for the default of all types.. value types such as `DateTime`, `int`, and classes for `null`. Then, your only other specific check is for `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Yeah, and it will return *`IsNull(0)`* as `true`. Really great and useful method.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It's about as useful as `DateTime.MinValue.IsNull()` and `String.Empty.IsNull()` returning `true`.

Comment: The 3rd and 4th definitions of null are 0, so it could be somewhat valid... http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/null

Comment: In very specific scenarios @charlieparker (those being: mathematics). Whilst writing code using this method.. it would make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Just playing the devil's advocate

Comment: `IsDefaultValue`—that's what (3) should be called.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to add check differenty for Value and Reference type object?

Value types can not be null.

> Does this externtion method handle all type of null check for any object?

It looks like (except value types)

> Any suggestion or improvement need to add in extention?

As I said value types cannot be `null`, so you can add an extra condition to check whether the type is value type or not,if so you can return `false`

```
if(obj.GetType().IsValueType) return false;
```

By the way if you write this before the `DateTime` check,your DateTime condition will become unreachable.It doesn't make sense anyway but it's your choice.If you want to return `true` when the value equals to `DateTime.MinValue` it's completely up to you.

Comment: Value type may be nullable like `int?`, in this case it should return true

Comment: @AnkushMadankar - You can have nullable value types, but you would be unable to pass them into this function which takes an object. It wouldn't compile.

Comment: @ansible Incorrect. It does.. and it will pass `null` through.

Comment: @ansible Code will compile, but I think `if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)` will handle nullable value type..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - Interesting - I'll need to give it a try tomorrow when I'm at my PC.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Then if you want to use my extra condition,put it after the first check `if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)` then I guess it makes sense.if the type is Nullable and has a null value it return false,but if it's non-nullable like normal in it will return false.